# Как кликнуть на элемент в Selenium?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу кликнуть на аватарку блога, и делаю это следующем образом:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)

url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/search/tatto+'

driver.get(url)

albums =  driver.find_element_by_class_name('avatar circle')
# albums.click()
a = albums.size
x = random.randint(-a['height'],a['height'] )
y = random.randint(-a['width'], a['width'])
# action = ActionChains(driver)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(albums, 10, 15).click().perform()
```

Все ломается на строке `albums =  driver.find_element_by_class_name('avatar circle')`
В чем проблема, подскажите?

Comment: что значит "ломается"?

Comment: Вылетает в exption

Answer (score 2):

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"avatar circle"}

вы всегда можете использовать `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_actions_search"]/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]').click()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]