# Проблемы с Selenium "element not interactable" (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Не могу ввести данные в input, пишет "element not interactable"
В чем проблема понять не могу, на другом сайте работало идеально

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

URL = 'https://playntrade.ru/auth/login?back=/shopstats/plans'
NAME = 'PloTheLive'
PASS = 'pass'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name('login_email').send_keys(NAME)
sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Global/Автодобавление/main.py", line 12, in <module>
driver.find_element_by_name('login_email').send_keys(NAME)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Comment: Могу предположить, что разумнее будет делать не sleep(1), а while not driver.find_element_by_name('login_email'): sleep. Скорее всего, элемент за время этой паузы просто не успевает подгрузиться

Comment: Переписал как вы сказали, такая же ошибка, по всей видимости элемент прогружается сразу же, при открытии сайта и проблема не в этом, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы всегда можете использовать `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/section/article/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/div/div[2]/input').send_keys(NAME)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1173493/234134)

Answer (score 0):

Так же описанное явление наблюдается, если искомый элемент находится внутри Frame(iframe), а программист этого не заметил.
В таком случае перед обращением к элементу следует сначала переключиться на данный участок кода с помощью browser.switch_to.frame('имя фрейма')
После операций внутри фрейма не забудьте переключиться обратно:
browzer.switch_to.default_content()